# Want to display date in QQ-YYYY format in Kendo Grid

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid in MVC and I want to format a date column in QQ-YYYY format. Ex: if date is Jan 23 2021, it should display as 01-2021. I tried the below code but not working. Please help. My code is as below.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.TeamRank).Title("Team Rank").Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.ETA).Title("Forecast").ClientTemplate("#=formatDate(ETA)#");
}
```

My formatDate function

'''

```
function formatDate(ETA) {
    var CurrentQuarter = ((ETA.getMonth - 1) / 3) + 1;
    return CurrentQuarter + "-" + ETA.getFullYear;
}
```

'''

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date parsing and formatting tools from Kendo.

```
function formatDate(ETA /* Jan 23 2021 */) {
    var date = kendo.parseDate(ETA, "MMM dd yyyy");
    var quarter = Math.floor((date.getMonth() + 3) / 3);
    var formattedDate = kendo.toString(quarter, "00") + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    return formattedDate;
}

console.log(formatDate("Jan 23 2021"));
```